# angular controller function broken

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

Below is a scratch of an application I'm working on:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/bower_components/angular-youtube-mb/dist/angular-youtube-embed.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['youtube-embed']);

            myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
              // have a video id
              $scope.theBestVideo = 'i9MHigUZKEM';
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <youtube-video video-id="theBestVideo"></youtube-video>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't find what is wrong, but I can see the `Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined` error in the chrome console. I think it's all there: the app, the controller, one bound to another. Can somebody point me out what is the problem here?

edit: in case it's relevant, I'm using 1.2.28 angular.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small mistake is there.
**Change**:`<html ng-app>` 
**To**: `<html ng-app="myApp">`

Comment: yeah, right... this is how you end up using boilerplates... Btw, what is recommended - attaching ng-app to <html> or to <body> tag?

Comment: attaching ng-app to  is better idea.

Comment: There is no big difference where you put ng-app.

If you put it on <body> then you have a smaller scope for AngularJS which is slightly faster.

Comment: AngularJS will bootstrap the first ng-app it finds! That's it. If you have more than one ng-app, it will only process the first one. This why you are getting error.

Answer (score 1):

I have verified your code,only thing you need to change is that remove this line

```html
<html ng-app>
```

. Because you have used two html tags at beginning that's why you are getting error  Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined.